# Shared test code in multi-project Maven Java environment

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have a Maven multi-project set-up with a parent POM, one library-type jar and several application-jars using this library. Now I'd like to take advantage of this library-type jar's testing facility (especially the API mocking features) in the unit tests of the applications to avoid repeating the same unit test code in all of the applications, which I am doing now. However it seems this is not trivial.

Any of you done this, or any other solutions to suggest to this problem?

[edit]
clarification:

If I have applications A, B and library L, and dependencies like this:

```
A -> L <- B
```

I would like the test code of above have dependencies correspondingly:

```
A' -> L' <- B'
```

So the application's test code could see the library's test code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174560/sharing-test-code-in-maven

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247199/share-test-resources-between-maven-projects?lq=1

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. Seems I was not using right search keywords.