# Maven - adding test resources from another project

Tags: maven

I want to add test resources from another module.

My tests ran ok with the following

```
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>DEPENDENCY_A/src/main/resources</directory>
    </testResource>

</testResources>
```

DEPENDENCY_A has pom packaging, however, my tests cannot the same external resources by adding it as a test-pom-dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>DEPENDENCY_A</groupId>
    <artifactId>DEPENDENCY_A</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please help :) How do I access resources in DEPENDENCY_A in my unit tests? Maybe I'm missing something obvious in Java basics :(

Comment: Looks like duplicate. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247199/share-test-resources-between-maven-projects

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies are artifact, libraries, jars, ... not resources. So this idea is not suitable.

You can use the [copy-resources goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) of the [Maven Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/):

> *copies resources to an output directory. This goal requires that you configure the resources to be copied, and specify the outputDirectory.*

See also [Maven model, resource](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.1/maven-model/maven.html#class_resource).

Comment: How do I access resources/file in DEPENDENCY_A_JAR in my unit tests? Maybe I'm missing something obvious in Java basics :(

Comment: @lingo_journey If you use [Maven's Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) test resources reside in `src/test/resources` of your Maven project.

Comment: Thanks, if I want a Unit test to use resources from an external jar... what's the best practice please? How do I run the copy-resources goal against a jar?

Comment: @lingo_journey Did you follow the link codesalsa gave you in the comment to your question?

Comment: Thanks, I did, however, I need to use the "main" (instead of test) resources of external JAR-A.