# How to include test code in maven artifact?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, maven-2, maven

I have following problem module core contains test utils which is resused in dependent modules.

How to use this code in those modules? (maven dosen't include this code by convention, but how to solve this problem)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing Test code in Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174560/sharing-test-code-in-maven)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use maven-source-plugin to [create a test jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html). It will be published along with your normal jar as an artifact of the build.