# In Intellij is it possible for one module to depend on the tests of another module

Tags: unit-testing, module, intellij-idea

I have a multimodule project in Intellij and I have a bunch of cucumber fixtures in the test sources of one submodule that I'd like to reuse in another submodule. If I add the other module, as a dependency then its normal ouptut directory gets added to the junit classpath but not its tests output.

Is it possible to have intellij also export a modules test directories and allow other modules to use them?

Comment: The tests output should be added to the classpath. Is your project imported from Maven?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing Test code in Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174560/sharing-test-code-in-maven)

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can but it's not simple.

So you have ***Module-A*** and ***Module-B***.

***Module-B*** has a `TestClass` that perhaps extends an AbstractClass or uses some static helpers from ***Module-A***

**Note:** This will only work in intellij, if you are using maven or gradle you will need to check this will still build ok.

Here is what you need to do.

1. Goto **Project Structure...** `(Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S - win/linux)`
2. Goto Modules and Look at **Module-A**'s **Path** Tab
3. Take a note of the Test output path or copy this. It could be something like this: `C:\dev\projects\myProject\moduleA\build\testclasses` or similar.
4. Goto Modules and select **Module-B** and look at its **Dependencies** Tab.
5. You may already have a dependency on **Module-A** in here for compile time and thats ok.Click on the **+** or type `(Alt+Insert)` and add a new Library (No 2 on the options)
6. On the choose libraries screen select the **New Library...** button. Select the **Java** option.
7. In the dialog that pops up goto the build folder you had above `C:\dev\projects\myProject\moduleA\build\testclasses` and click **OK**. You will now have the classes for your **Module-A** in here. Name it something suitable `Module-A Tests` and change the **Level** option to **Module Library**.
8. Click the **+** button `(Alt+Insert)` to add the source in as well. Navigate to the test src files. E.G.: `C:\dev\projects\myProject\moduleA\src\test` and add this and you will now have a Sources added as well.

   9. Click **OK** and you will come back to the **Project Structure** dialog.
   10. Now you will have a new Library added to your dependencies. Change the **Scope** to **Test**
   11. Press **OK** at the bottom and your done. You might need to make/clean the project.

And now you have test depencies linked between modules.

If you can think of a better solution please let me know but this is the simplest way I have found to do it.

Comment: I really wish I didn't search for this.. ( I'm lazy I guess I'll just move the few abstract problem test classes I have to *Module B*, don't really like it because some *Module A* tests will have to be moved to *Module B* even though they are testing code in *Module A*, but oh well - it is simpler

Comment: Excellent and well-written instructions - follow them carefully.

Answer (score 1):

maybe, but you should be doing this through your automated build, i.e. in maven, not your IDE. if you publish the tests of a maven module as a separate dependency (something that I do), you can add the tests jar as a dep of the other module. IDEA of course will handle this automatically.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html

Comment: would love to use maven, but that is not an option. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: one option is just include things in your production sources, or create a "test" module which contains test stuff in the production sourcepath...

Comment: There's no way whatsoever to get IntelliJ to allow the test classes in one project to be accessible from the test classes of another dependent project? For example, running & debugging tests locally through the IDE

Comment: Doing it through Maven, makes it work in Maven. But in my case, IntelliJ still refuses to pick that up and resolve it. I.e., my IDE is still full of red marks.