# m2eclipse workspace resolution classpth and test folder

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

I am using m2eclipse for manage my classpath in eclipse, and i have a problem when i want use test-compile goal in eclipse.

i have 2 projects A & B, project B depend A for class (in folder target/classes) and test class (in folder target/test-classes). If I run test-compile goal in m2 eclipse launcher with parameter M2_WORKSPACE_RESOLUTION=true the compilation can not find test classes of project A.

In command line everythings are ok.
If I use M2_WORKSPACE_RESOLUTION=false everythings are ok.

How can I force m2eclipse to use test class with workspace resolution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's an issue of M2eclipse:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352962

The dependency resolution will work (it seems) with in the JVM that is running Eclipse.  But if another JVM is launched then it won't.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare a dependency on the test classes of project A explicitly. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174560/sharing-test-code-in-maven) on how to do that. Test classes are normally not packaged in the artifact. That's why you can't access those classes from project B.

Comment: I already add the test-jar in my pom.xml, all is good with command line, it is just the workspace resolution in m2eclipse is broken. If i disable workspace resolution all is good