# Use class from test scope in other module

Tags: java, maven, testing, scope

I have a module as part of a framework that provides common features to other modules. I have created a class (UtilitiesForTesting) that provides some utils to be used only in my tests, so it's stored in test section of the module.

The module has the following structure:

```
project
    -src
       -main
         -java
           -com
             -company
               -product
                 +Foo
       -test
         -java
           -com
             -company
               -product
                 +FooTest
               -utility
                 +UtilitiesForTesting
```

UtilitiesForTesting class is visible inside the project but when I compile it the resulting jar does not contains any test class.

Now I want to use the modules in other modules, because I need this common functionality, but also I want to use testing utilities.

I don't want to place UtilitiesForTesting in the /main section, since I don't want to allow the use of this class in production code, only in test.

I want to have just a module that provides production classes to other module and test util to the same module, but restricting using the test utilities in the /main section.

Is there any way to use a class of the test scope of a module in other module?

Comment: You can always export it to an external library containing nothing but testtools, and just add a dependency to this library in both modules/applications/projects.

Comment: Yes, but in this way this module could be imported with ´compile´ scope by other modules and use it production code. I want to restrict the use only for testing.

Comment: Then the *other* modules can import with actual test scope. This example *isn't* "test scope", which applies to imports; it's dealing with the test classpath.

Comment: Specifically, check out flicken's answer in the duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/174670/423991, that should solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks for point me to the previously answered question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your pom.xml, under maven-jar-plugin, add below goal.

```
`<goal>test-jar</goal>`
```

All the files under src/test/java are compiled and bundled into artifact-test.jar.

In another module, if u want to use this artifact-test jar, use below configuration in dependency tag.

```
 `<artifactId>artifactid</artifactId>
<type>test-jar</type>'
```