# How to reuse classes from /src/test/java in different project?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have a class in a commons library that I placed into `/src/test/java`. Then I want to reuse that class in any project having the commons library as dependency.

But the file cannot be imported.

Common custom library:

```
/src/test/java/com/myproject/utils/TestfileReader.java
```

Implementation project:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

usage:

```
/src/test/java/com/myproject/itest/SomeTest.java

import com.myproject.utils.TestfileReader;
```

Result: the import cannot be resolved.

But if I copy that file to `/src/main/java/...` it can be found correctly. So my commons library seems to be fine in general.

Question: how can I make this file visible only to my tests, while keeping it in `/src/test/java` folder?

Comment: put it in a separate project, add a dependency to this project in each project where you want to use it in a test.

Comment: So I necessarily have to put that class under `/src/main/java`?

Comment: So, you added a pom entry for that dependency, but is there such lib actually? (at least in your local repository)

Comment: @Tom I think the problem is that the class is under the test classes, not under source

Comment: @Tom yes of course. As written if I move that file to `/src/main/java` inside the commons library, it is found correctly.

Comment: @membersound it seems quite unlogical that a same class, which is designed to test one specific class in project A can also be used to test a class in project B. if there is, there's something about code-reuse missing in the projects. So I'm not sure you can import classes under test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing Test code in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174560/sharing-test-code-in-maven)

Comment: Then why is there no "scope" tag? Please read the dupe, it might solve the issue.

Comment: @Stultuske Well in this case it's a common filereader that reads files from a path (provided as parameter), and processes the file in a specific way. If I need that routine in multiple projects, I think it's totally fine to reuse that class. But as it is only suitable for testing, I tend to not include it in the main path...

Comment: @membersound so add it in a seperate (small) library, which you put as dependency and re-use in both projects' tests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this by specifying the type to test-jarscope.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What if `my-commons` also contains classes that should be reused from `/src/main/java`? Would I then have to include the dependency 2 times, where one has `test-jar`?

Comment: At least it works when adding the dependency 2 times, with one having the testscope.

Comment: @membersound its a common practice to add the dependency for the src and for the test

Answer (score 0):

You can control whether your resources under your src/test folder will get shipped or not, e.g. via the `maven-resource-plugin` See here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/testResources-mojo.html

An example here would copy all sources found under `src/test/java` into your final build.

```
<testResources>
  <testResource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following:

- Create a jar file from the project that you want to share in
  different projects.
- Use this jar file as dependencies by giving
  group id, artifact id and version.
- Remember to add index of this jar
  file in your external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, one can do it..

First You need to navigate to `Build Path-->Configure Build Path--> Source tab`

then in the Source tab `search/check [your Project Name]/src/main/java` and change

`"contains test sources"` from No to Yes and save it.

This will resolved issue of import packages from "src/test/java" to "src/main/java" successfully